# Why was it decided in 1956 to abolish the spelling чорт (devil) in favor of чёрт?

Tags: история-языка, правописание, орфография

I read in Wiktionary:

> **чорт**
>
> This spelling of the word was officially abolished in 1956 in favor of чёрт and is no longer in use. Both variants are pronounced identically.
>
> ([Source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82))

I see in Ngram Google Books that it was indeed common before 1956 to write **чорт** in books.

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chort) that in Belorussian and Ukrainian, this word is still spelt as **чорт**.

The new spelling, **чёрт**, has a disadvantage: if the dots over **е** are omitted as usual, the word becomes indistinguishable in writing from the plural genitive of the Russian word **черта** (line, trait, feature).

What was the motivation to officially abolish the spelling **чорт** in favor of **чёрт** in 1956? Could it be that someone superstitious wanted to save Russians from explicitly referring to devils and thought that replacing **o** by **ё/e** would do the trick to keep black powers at bay?

Comment: I would guess it's to standardize the spelling. Russian doesn't really have any words with чо left, I think only чокнутый. Чёрный, чёрствый, чёлка, чёткий, чёрточка , etc all use чё. Ukrainian still uses чо as far as I know, such as in the city Чоронобиль (Chernobyl), but not Russian.

Comment: @Curiosity : What about чопорный?

Comment: I guess that if it had been just standardization, people would now write чёкнутый и чёпорный.

Comment: There is actually a rule I found here: https://touch.otvet.mail.ru/question/202064316

Comment: По современным нормам — черт (чёрт).
После шипящих в корнях слов под ударением вместо "о" пишется "ё", если при изменении слова или образовании родственного слова в этом корне появляется "е".
Можно изменить так, чтобы появилась "е"? Можно: черти. Значит, "ё".

Comment: Curiosity,  could you make it an answer? Don't leave it in comments. Черт -черти—чертенок.

Comment: Looks like shabunc's answer covers this now!

Comment: @Curiosity words with "чо" are certainly rare but not quite "doesn't really have" kind of rare. Consider "зрачок", "плечо", "пучок", "девчонка", "крючок", "бардачок". Admittedly "плечо" is the only one I can think of where it isn't a suffix.

Comment: @RomanSt I meant starting with чо, but you're right, there's no reason to separate them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before the standardization both forms, `черт`/`чёрт` and `чорт` were in actual use, like we see from this google ngram chart:

[image]

(Strictly speaking, we should sort out черт derived from `черта` but this won't change the very fact that both form co-existed.)

In Russian grammar there's a concept called `проверочные слова` - in short it's about existence of words that are pronounced and/or spelled in such way that we justify the spelling of some other word. When it comes to `чёрт`, the one form has been chosen over another and the actual reason was that there's a lot of words with `черт` (но `ё`) - `чертовской`, `чертяка`, `чертыхаться`, `чертёнок` and choosing `чёрт` was a very natural and intuitive thing to do.

With `чопорный` we do not have any similar situation, basically it's only `чопорный` so it was left the way it is (well, in Russian it used to be words like `чепори́ться`, `чепу́ри́ться` but they are obsolete). As of `чокнутый` by the way people quite often misspell is a `чёкнутый` and that usage in its turn lead to the existence of word `чекану́тый`.

Still, just like always I want to insist that it's more an issue of memoization than anything else. For instance, there is [`чёрствый`,](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9) not `чорствый` and one just should learn it.

Comment: Чепуриться --казачий диалект, чепурной, до сих пор действующее  слово,  как разговорное.

Comment: Черствый --черстветь,  так же,  как черный - -чернеть. Правило вроде действует.

Comment: Чопорный--чопорность.

Comment: @V.V. чопорность не считается - там ударение там же, остальные примеры да!

Comment: Берите себе, я просто помогаю, чем могу.

Answer (score -2):

> What was the motivation to officially abolish the spelling **чорт** in favor of **чёрт** in 1956?

Definitely it was NOT officially abolished from the language. The official direction of language politics in USSR was to remove any occurence of **Ё** letter.

I think **чёрт** started to appear since 1900s years effectively pushing off old word **чорт**. General sentiment was to disapprove the policy of Russian Csar Nikolai II, during his late terms or ruling. Right after he lost Russian-Japaneese war of 1905. Especially during his "business engagements" with Rasputin.

Comment: this answer is wrong and not backed by any evidence.

Comment: @shabunc А в 1956 году только подтвердили откат имевших место ранее ошибочных изменений по "искоренению Ё". Все причины чисто политические, язык не меняется "туда-сюда" в рамках каких-то там тридцати лет.